# Table constraint from maximum no of child records

Tags: sql

Consider the following schema to student and several courses.

```
Student(Regno:integer, Sname:string, Degree:string, Age:integer)
Course(Coursecode:string, Cname:string, Credit:integer)
Enrolled(Regno:integer, Coursecode:string)
```

My problem is, SQL script to ensure that a student enrolls for maximum of 8 courses? 
is there any possibility to use CONSTRAINTS for achieve this?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: this is a question from sample questionnaire. any rdbms will be fine. If you can provide a solution for MYSQL or SQL Server, will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do with SQL Server, but you can't do it only with constraints. The easiest thing to do is to use a trigger for insert/update that will roll back if you attempt to enroll a student to too many courses.

Assuming the `Enrolled` table have a unique constraint on the combination of `Regno` and `Coursecode` (which it should - that should be it's primary key), you can use a trigger as simple as this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER EnsureMaxEnrolled 
ON Enrolled
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Enrolled As E
    JOIN Inserted As I
        ON E.Regno = I.Regno
    GROUP BY E.Regno
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 8
) 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
GO
```

However, I would probably think twice about using such a trigger - the requirement of a maximum number of courses per student is a business requirement, I don't think it's the database's job to enforce business rules.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could enforce such a constraint in the database as follows:

1. Add an `int` field
2. Add a constraint so that this new `int` must be between 1 and 8 inclusive
3. Create a unique index on the new field + your student identifier

If you do the above, it is impossible to have more than 8 records per student.

That being said, a rule like is probably best enforced at the application level and not in the database.